# Calendario Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, date, bucle-for, function

¿Podría alguien orientarme sobre como sacar un calendario de este estilo? En la función debo de pasarle año y mes a mostrar, tal que quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function calendario(anio,mes){

var meses = ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'];

for(var i=0;i<=11;i++){
    var fecha=new Date(anio,mes);
    if(fecha.getMonth()==4){
        meses.push(fecha);
        document.write(fecha +"<br>");

        document.write('<table border="1">');
        document.write("<h3>"+meses);
        document.write('<tr>');

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero tienes que tomar los días que tiene el mes que elegiste y meterlo dentro de un arreglo, para que dependiendo del año y del mes, tome los días, y ya después lo metes en una tabla recorriendo ese arreglo de días, al final solo cuentas los días, si ese día es igual a 7, ingresa un nuevo renglón y a ese valor numero 7 lo pintas de rojo.

```js
    function calendario(anio,mes){
    
    var meses = ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'];
     var mesReal = mes-1;
        var fecha=new Date(anio,mesReal);
        var dias = [];
        while (fecha.getMonth() === mesReal) {
          dias.push(new Date(fecha));
          fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1);
        }
        document.write(meses[mesReal] +"<br>");
        document.write('<table border="1"><tr>');
        var week = 0;
        for(var i=1;i<=dias.length; i++) {
          week++;
          if (week === 7) {     
            document.write("<td style='color:red;'>"+i+"</td>");
            document.write("<tr>");
            week =0;
          } else {
          document.write("<td>"+i+"</td>");
          }
        }
    }
    calendario(2001,3);
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Estupenda explicación, me ha servido de ayuda. ¡Gracias! Saludos.